# I have been facing some issue during implementing google map in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

```
2015-08-14 16:30:00.533 TryMapMe[3206:96691] Google Maps SDK for iOS    (M4B) version: 1.10.17867.0 

2015-08-14 16:30:01.342    TryMapMe[3206:96691] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts    remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The    operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)"    UserInfo=0x7fb2eb78a800 {data=<CFData 0x7fb2eb7808a0    [0x10faa2180]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes =    0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}} 

2015-08-14    16:30:01.449 TryMapMe[3206:96691] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2    attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus    Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus    error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7fb2eb642ce0 {data=<CFData 0x7fb2eb635a50    [0x10faa2180]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes =    0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}} 

2015-08-14    16:30:05.651 TryMapMe[3206:96691] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1    attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus    Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus    error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7fb2eb6759c0 {data=<CFData 0x7fb2eb652590    [0x10faa2180]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes =    0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}} 

2015-08-14    16:30:14.552 TryMapMe[3206:96691] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0    attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus    Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus    error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7fb2eb5284d0 {data=<CFData 0x7fb2eb7a63f0    [0x10faa2180]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes =    0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}} 

2015-08-14    16:30:14.553 TryMapMe[3206:96691] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B)    cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus    Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus    error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7fb2eb5284d0 {data=<CFData 0x7fb2eb7a63f0    [0x10faa2180]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes =    0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}} 

2015-08-14    16:30:14.553 TryMapMe[3206:96691] Your key may be invalid for your    bundle ID: com.abc.com
```

I got my api key generated in every way but i m getting those mentioned error and map view is empty

Comment: I have followed the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start), and import the `Google map on iOS` successfully. So I think you should try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my map working.It is working fine so far